# Server down when trying to save more than one image using Imagick and PHP

Tags: php, openshift, fpdf, imagick

I have been stumbling over this for a couple of days.
I have an imagick object `$img` that reads a pdf of two pages, in a webservice.
I am trying to save each page as `jpg` image.

```
for($i = 0;$i < $num_pages; $i++){
   file_put_contents(logfile,"index = ".$i." \r\n\r\n",FILE_APPEND);
   $img->setIteratorIndex($i);
   $img->writeImage('workorders/'.$jobSFID.$i.".jpg");
}

file_put_contents(logfile,"test 7 \r\n\r\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

When I remove the loop and save one page only... all goes well.
But with the loop, saving the two pages, it breaks down, never reaches `test 7` logging statement, and gives `503 server temporarily unavailable` some times, and other times `502 proxy error reading from remote server`.

Comment: What is your maximum execution time for php scripts? How long does it take to render one jpg image? The script could reach this timeout and would then be terminated, which - depending on your configuration - could result in the error message that you describe

Comment: Did you enable PHP errors? `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Maybe you are then able to see the error and fix it.

Comment: try adding usleap(10), or more imagick will take time create image


      for($i = 0;$i < $num_pages; $i++){
     usleep(10);
      file_put_contents(logfile,"index = ".$i." \r\n\r\n",FILE_APPEND);
      $img->setIteratorIndex($i);
      $img->writeImage('workorders/'.$jobSFID.$i.".jpg");
      }

Comment: How about some server logs?

Comment: @sotn0r I have set the maximum execution time in my webservice for the sake of testing:

ini_set('max_execution_time', 120000);
ini_set("memory_limit", "6400M");

No luck

Comment: I'd recommend getting errors to display, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display Figuring this out without the error is hard.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely to be another problem with your code, that turning on error reporting, or looking in the appropriate log file will reveal, however your code probably doesn't do quite what you want it to do.

Altough setting the "iteratorIndex" affects which image is current in a sequence of images, it doesn't actually separate that particular image out.

It should be much more reliable to separate a single image with `Imagick::getImage` to ensure that only a single page is written.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $num_pages; $i++){
   $img->setIteratorIndex($i);
   $pageImage = $img->getImage();
   $pageImage->writeImage('workorders/'.$jobSFID.$i.".jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions... but it didn't work.. I checked php.log file on the server after enabling errors display... no trace for an error...

Comment: I have also granted write permission on the server for "Workorders" directory... no luck neither